# EF 6 Update query and Where clause with list of integers comparison

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, entity-framework

In EF 6.0 I want to update some records based on a WHERE filter. Records which I recognize from a list of integers of ids. The problem is it sees the id list as an nvarchar "61, 62, 63" and the IN operator does not work between integer and nvarchar.

```
var status = MyEnum.MyEnumValue;
var idList = new List<int>(...);

context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated(
    $"UPDATE MyTable SET MyCustomStatus = {status} WHERE Id IN ({string.Join(", ", idList)})"
);
```

**error**

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
  HResult=0x80131904
  Message=Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '61, 62, 63' to data type int.
  Source=Core Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
...
```

Do you know any solutions?

Comment: It is interpolated into a parameter that has the type of varchar. Instead, you can concatenate where part into interpolated part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can opt to use  the [ExecuteSqlRaw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlraw?view=efcore-7.0) method in order to use the raw SQL strings with the parameters provided separately.

Example:

```cs
 var status = "my custom status";

 // Create a parameter for the list of integers
 var idListParameter = string.Join(",", idList.Select(id => $"@p{id}"));
 var parameters = idList.Select((id, index) => new SqlParameter($"@p{id}", id)).ToList();

 // Add a new SqlParameter for the status parameter
 parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@status", status));

 _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(
    $"UPDATE MyTable SET MyCustomStatus = @status WHERE Id IN ({idListParameter})",parameters.ToArray()
 );
```

Comment: This works. I would also add for others to check if `idListParameter` is empty, otherwise the query will be constructed with wrong syntax.